# TypeError: 'frozenset' object is not callable; Python2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "sample.py", line 7, in 
>           from ctypes.util import find_library
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ctypes-1.0.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/ctypes/util.py", line 46, in 
>           import re, tempfile, errno
>         File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tempfile.py", line 35, in 
>           from random import Random as _Random
>         File "/usr/lib/python2.7/random.py", line 49, in 
>           import hashlib as _hashlib
>         File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/hashlib.py", line 115, in 
>           """
>       TypeError: 'frozenset' object is not callable

How to fix this problem?

Comment: How do you expect us to help you if you don't post your code?

Comment: What does your code look like? Show us line 7 on sample.py

Comment: Please provide more side information.

Answer (score 3):

I received today the same error.
For me the solution was to replace: `except ImportError:` with `except:` in line 129 of my_project_path/eggs/hashlib-20081119-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/hashlib.py

Seems this was related to value `md_meth_names` for `funcName` and this discussion helped me: https://askubuntu.com/questions/575598/python-attributeerror-with-hashlib-no-such-attribute-openssl-md-meth-names

Comment: This helped me on Windows 7 too! Thanks!  For me, the egg file was in my install dir for Python: C:\Python\lib\site-packages\hashlib-20081119-py2.7-win-amd64.egg.  I made a backup copy, then renamed the original as hashlib.zip (egg files are just zip files), then unzipped it, fixed the hashlib.py file as discussed above, rezipped it, and renamed the zip file with the original .egg file name.  No more TypeError for frozenset!

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't have any code, my best guess if you did something like this:

```
my_frozenset_obj(some_index)
```

instead of this:

```
my_frozenset_obj.pop()
```

If you want to be able to access the items by an index, then you should be using a data structure that is not a set.